# iOs App 1000+ Data Entries CoreData or simple Array?

Tags: ios, arrays, core-data

I have about 1000+ Data Entries (Number, Name, Age, Color). On the first view the user can imput a numer which will output the corresponding entries on the second view.

Do I have to work with CoreData or is it a good solution to use a simple Array to store the data?

Does the Array use to much memory? Is the Array to slow?

Answer (score 3):

With 1000+ strings along with other data you are likely to run into memory problems rather soon. Also, if you are not using an incremental store such as Core Data provides, changing the smallest unit of your data would require rewriting the entire list.

Core Data would be my choice, but there is a somewhat steep learning curve. It is not really that difficult, but it takes maybe some time to get used to. The `NSFetchedResultsController` will ensure good performance and low memory footprint.

If, however, persistence is not really an issue and you are actually *calculating* the data (e.g. based on the initial number), you might want to use a different scheme. For example, in a standard `UITableView` you could calculate the data to be displayed *ad hoc* in the `datasource` methods based on the index path - you would then have to calculate only the data for the visible cells. Depending on the demands of the data model, you might have some performance issues when scrolling very fast - this is difficult to predict.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that he should use Core Data for persisting the data, not when data is being calculated.

Comment: I second this. 1000 entries absolutely calls for persisting data. Also, NSFetchedResultsController makes populating tables from Core Data a walk in the park.

Answer (score 0):

There are different considerations why you should use CoreData instead of a simple NSArray.

Ask yourself questions like:

- Do you need to persist the data?
- Do you need all the data at once for displaying?
- Do you perform search queries on the data?

Depending on your answers you can choose CoreData or a NSArray. Keeping all the data in memory is nonetheless expensive and you should avoid it anyway. In my opinion I would try to go with CoreData although it produces some overhead in the first line.